# Restrict permission for AWS ECS RegisterTaskDefinition

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-ecs

I want to restrict which IAM user or role can call `RegisterTaskDefinition` for specific task definition but looks like task definition does not support resource type in IAM policy. It only support tag in condition key.

How can I restrict which IAM user or role can call `RegisterTaskDefinition`?

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/APIReference/API_RegisterTaskDefinition.html
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/list_amazonelasticcontainerservice.html

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Resource-level permission control for ECS Task Definitions is currently not available.

[ECS]: Resource-level permissions for Task Definitions
https://github.com/aws/containers-roadmap/issues/929