# Which resource arn to use in Aws Codepipeline ECS IAM permission?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-codepipeline

I am following    [AWS's code pipeline documentation for Iam permissions.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/security-iam.html) According to the docs these are the minimum permissions for ECS standard deployment.

```
{
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Action": [
        "ecs:DescribeServices",
        "ecs:DescribeTaskDefinition",
        "ecs:DescribeTasks",
        "ecs:ListTasks",
        "ecs:RegisterTaskDefinition",
        "ecs:UpdateService"
    ],
    "Resource": "resource_ARN"
},
```

I am confused about which resource arn I am supposed to use. Is it the task definition's or ECS service's arn I should be using?

Comment: It should be the ECS service's arn

Comment: @TimBassett When I looked through Aws docs I could not find it. Would you tell me where it is mentioned to use service's arn?

Comment: I have the exact same permissions but they only work if I add "*" in `Resource`. Tried adding ARNs for the service, cluster, task-definition and ECR repository (separately and all together). None worked. Did anyone figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

I was working with the same permissions and changing `Resource: *` to `Resource: "ECS_SERVICE_ARN"` did not work. What eventually worked was splitting the permissions into 2 parts like so:

```
  {
    "Effect" : "Allow",
    "Action" : [
      "ecs:DescribeTaskDefinition",
      "ecs:RegisterTaskDefinition",
    ],
    "Resource" : "*"
  },
  {
    "Effect" : "Allow",
    "Action" : [
      "ecs:UpdateService",
      "ecs:ListTasks",
      "ecs:DescribeTasks",
      "ecs:DescribeServices",
    ],
    "Resource" : "ECS_SERVICE_ARN"
  }
```

Resource-level permission control for ECS Task Definitions is currently not available, as mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64019346/11409321

Answer (score -2):

```
"Resource" : [
    "arn:aws:ecr:us-east-1:808394661234:repository/myrepositoryname"
]
```

Where you will want to check the `us-east-1` part to match your region. The number will have to match your Account ID. To get that go to the top right menu to get the Account ID. Just remove any `-`. Then lastly the `myrepositoryname` should match the name you used to create the ECR for instance.